# Locked Out of HTC One -- Unknown Password

Tags: locked-out, htc-one

I have an htc one me, I put a privacy protection but I forgot the password.
What can I do to unlock my phone?

I have tried the different passwords that I thought I used it failed. I really need to use my phone to contact my friends but I can't access it because of the privacy protection password.

Please help me to remove it.

My brothers tried to unlock it but failed and I am scared of taking it to the service centre, due to concerns about the quality of service.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please take a look at our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), which holds some first-aid and links to useful information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't remember your password , there is only one way to fix this but it will wipe all your data...

Follow this steps to fix this:

**Turn off your device**

1. Press and hold the **VOLUME DOWN** button, and then press and hold the **POWER button**.
2. Wait for the screen with the three Android images to appear, and then release the **POWER** and **VOLUME DOWN** buttons.
3. Press **VOLUME DOWN** to select FACTORY RESET, and then press the **POWER** button.

The **boot** may take some minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the Android Device Manager, this is a simple fix. Open up the device manager from a desktop computer and set a temporary password on the phone. You can use that temporary password to get past the lock screen. Otherwise, you will need to factory reset the phone.